# TypeError: VideoCapture() takes no arguments

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, opencv

I am trying to make a motion detector using python and opencv. All was good but after sometime when rerunning two cells of my code, it said

```
TypeError: VideoCapture() takes no arguments
```

Those code were:

> TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in    1 import cv2
> ----> 2 cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
>
> TypeError: VideoCapture() takes no arguments

Please help me I am very frustrated due to this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39929166/cv2-python-videocapture0-unexpected-argument

Comment: Please also provide the code and not just one line of it